# location tag totally ignored

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am developing asp.net application where there is need to upload files to http server. I am stuck with upload limit 4 MB. I can change it with creating following section in web.config file:

```
    <configuration>
        <system.web>
            <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="204800" executionTimeout="600" />
        </system.web>
    </configuration>
```

Problem is that this setting cannot be customized by moving these same lines to location tag:

```
<configuration>
    <location path="ftp_upload.aspx">
        <system.web>
            <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="204800" executionTimeout="600" />
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>
```

IIS server just completely ignores this setting without issuing any warning or error message. I cannot understand that because in many other only minor errors in web.config it throws exceptions (for example when I forgot to set allowOverride parameter to true in parent web.config).

Comment: Did you try restarting the server? Could you accept a few of the answers on your previous questions?  People want points for their answers...

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to your config in the same location entry

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
       <requestFiltering>
           <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2048000000"/>
       </requestFiltering>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Note that the units are in bytes rather that kbyes... or something like that.

Comment: I already have this section in global settings. Have tried to move it into location tag with no success. But as I know this setting has default value of 30 MB. When I try to upload gradually bigger and bigger files, operation clearly fails on 4 MB border.

Comment: Are they Excel files?  We went several rounds with MS Tech support about a bug with uploading office files.  The files actually upload but the permissions were changed so IIS couldn't do anything with them.